# How to call methods on a Java nested abstract class from JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Have this:

```
public abstract class A {

    public abstract static class B {

        public static void greet() {
            System.out.println("Hey");
        }

    }

}
```

You can do, in Java,

```
A.B.greet();
```

But in JRuby, how do I call that? I tried

```
A::B.greet
```

But it can't find the `greet()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `A::B` resolve to? I tried your code in JRuby 1.6.4 and 1.7.9 (just to see if there was any behaviour that had changed recently) and it worked fine.

Since the `A` class isn't in a package (but it might be in your real code, of course), I had to refer to it as `Java::A::B` and call the method as `Java::A::B.greet`, that's why I ask what `A::B` resolves to, could it be that the real problem is that you're not referring to the class by it's fully qualified package name, or haven't imported it?